# How to get one value from two columns

Tags: java, sql, jpa, openjpa

I have this:

```
column1 column2 column3
=======================  
1. A;    null;    E  
2. Z;     B;    null
```

I want to get this two lines but for the first one I get the value of **column2** if not null else I get the value of **column3**
the some logic for the second line.
so the result is :
(A;E) and (Z;B)

```
    JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery(entityManager);
    QSubject subject = QSubject.subject;
    BooleanExpression conditions = subject.id.eq(id);
    return query.from(subject).where(conditions)
            .list(subject.title,subject.dateModif,subject.dateCreation);
```

what I want if ***dateModif*** is null I want getting ***dateCreation***.

I think in sql there is **coalesce** to use in this situation, but I dont know how in java using openjpa;

Comment: Add you code sample how you are doing

Answer (score 0):

Use `coalesce()`:

```
select column1, coalesce(column2, column3) as column2
from t;
```

This function takes multiple arguments and returns the first non-`NULL` value.

Comment: You can use this in a typed Query as well: entityManager.createQuery("select coalesce(table.column2, table.column3) from table", String.class);